# Days 30/360 calendar calculator implementation

Tags: java, date, apache-poi, finance

I need to use a 30/360 day calendar implementation for a finance calculation.
Basically, 30/360 in finance terms mean that all months will be considered to have 30 days.

For my scenario I have a start date and a end date, I need to calculate the difference between them in 30/360 calendar.

Is there a existing java library for this implementation?

There is a Apache POI class Days360, but it bizarrely takes arguments as type double for the date parameters.

Comment: The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library offers this [`AccountingChronology`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/AccountingChronology.html). But I do not think that meets your needs. You might consider using it as a model to implement a [`java.time.chrono.Chronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html) on your own. You then have the *java.time* classes at your service.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a existing java library for this implementation?

That question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. And I don’t know the answer. So I am hurrying to pretend that you asked a programming question instead. Writing a method for your calculation isn’t hard.

```
public static long daysBetween(LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
    if (to.isBefore(from)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (from.getDayOfMonth() == 31) {
        from = from.withDayOfMonth(30);
    }
    if (to.getDayOfMonth() == 31) {
        to = to.withDayOfMonth(30);
    }

    long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(
            YearMonth.from(from), YearMonth.from(to));
    int daysSigned = to.getDayOfMonth() - from.getDayOfMonth();

    return 30 * months + daysSigned;
}
```

I’d like to show you a few examples of what it calculates. For this purpose I am using the following method:

```
public static void tryItOut(LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
    long result = daysBetween(from, to);
    System.out.format("%s - %s: %3d day/s%n", from, to , result);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
    tryItOut(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 1), LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 20));
    tryItOut(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 1), LocalDate.of(2021, Month.FEBRUARY, 1));
    tryItOut(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.FEBRUARY, 1), LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 13));
    tryItOut(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 30), LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 1));
    tryItOut(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 31), LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 1));
    tryItOut(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 25), LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MARCH, 31));
    tryItOut(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MARCH, 30), LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MARCH, 31));
    tryItOut(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 29), LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MARCH, 1));
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2020-02-01 - 2020-02-20:  19 day/s
> 2020-02-01 - 2021-02-01: 360 day/s
> 2021-02-01 - 2021-03-13:  42 day/s
> 2020-01-30 - 2020-02-01:   1 day/s
> 2020-01-31 - 2020-02-01:   1 day/s
> 2020-01-25 - 2020-03-31:  65 day/s
> 2020-03-30 - 2020-03-31:   0 day/s
> 2020-02-29 - 2020-03-01:   2 day/s
> ```

For passing `double` values to Apache POI it probably wouldn’t be hard to write a method that would convert a `LocalDate` to a `double`. But that library is for accessing Excel spreadsheets, so if that isn’t your need, I don’t think I’d bother (Excel is probably a TM of Microsoft).

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: I have already written a similar method. But if you had read my question correctly you would see that I'm asking for a existing implementation. The reason being 30/360 calendar and its variations are very common in the financial world. As such I would expect there to be a tried and tested implementation. So let me pretend that you posted a valid answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Navs I had deliberately read your question differently, which I also stated in the answer. I had thought I’d be doing you a favour that way, sorry that I was wrong about that. Now someone else have taken your question seriously as it stands and have closed it as off-topic. *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It's a great answer. It's hard to digest an inexplicable DV 